# Color of div hangs over the background image on hover over

Tags: html, css, hover

**Explanation**

Im trying to make a few buttons.
I have a background image on a div, parts of this images are transparent. The background image is a circle.
When the user hovers over that div it changes the background to purple showing through the transparent parts.
The div is 80px x 80px. Same with the background image.
The radius of the div is 100px;

**Problem**

When the user hovers over the div, there is a small part of the purple showing outside the background image.

How do I stop this from happening?

**HTML Code**

```
<div id='Menu'>
<div onclick="gotoPage('HomePage')" class='MenuItem' id='home'>
    Home
</div>
<div onclick="gotoPage('AboutUsPage')" class='MenuItem' id='team'>
    About Us
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#Menu
{
    width: 80px;
}
.MenuItem
{
    font-family: 'Share Tech', bold, sans-serif;
    background-image: url(../images/button.png);
    color: rgb(51, 0, 102);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    line-height: 80px;
}
.MenuItem:hover
{
    background-color: rgba(51, 0, 102, 1);
    color: darkgray;
    cursor: pointer;
    /**position: relative;
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    margin-bottom: -20px;**/
}
```

**[Example Page](http://fcrusade.com/stackoverflow/index.html)**

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle with your cod - http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Hmm...without seeing the code and the actual image...this could be a sub-pixel fuzziness issue when the border-radius is applied.

Comment: We need to see that ACTUAL image.

Comment: `border-radius` for a circle is usually 50%.

Comment: How would I show the image?

Comment: You would have to host it online somewhere...I use photobucket but there are others.

Comment: http://fcrusade.com/stackoverflow/index.html

Comment: Also, why have you got `<div onclick="gotoPage('HomePage')" class='MenuItem' id='home'`, rather than just `<a href="/home.html" class="home">home</a>`

Comment: because it's not going to a page. All the pages are preloaded

Answer (score -2, accepted):

***Assuming every thing is as you say***, I would only suggest that you add this to ensure the bg image is sized and located correctly:

```
background-position:center;
background-size:80px 80px;
```

Also, the `border-radius` should be amended to:

```
border-radius: 50%;
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/jqyWC/3/)

Comment: I am an idiot. sorry guys... The image itself does not make the full 80px :S

Comment: -1 I added the OP's original button image here http://jsfiddle.net/jqyWC/4/ and your solution doesn't fix the issue. The OP needs to correct the image itself.

Comment: @SighFye My solution makes changing the image size optional.

Answer (score 0):

The overlapping image for your button isn't the full 80 x 80;

I changed background position in the fiddle to compensate but now the hover color bleeds to the bottom.

You need to fix the image itself or change the overall size of the button which is what is demonstrated on the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/69Jaw/ and the code below.

```
border-radius: 78px;
background-position: -2px -1px;
width: 77px;
height: 78px;
line-height: 78px;
```